# Push a div over a other div?

Tags: html, css

I have a circle over my rectangle but I want the circle to go over the end of the rectangle, so that one half is in the rectangle and the other half is out.

How can I achieve that?

[image]

Here is my attempt:

```css
.wrapper-project {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.project-pill {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4vw;
  background-color: #DBDDDC;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 35vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  border-radius: 4vw 4vw 0 0;
  width: 95%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  heigth: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-rigth: auto;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.7vw;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: poppins;
}

.text {
  heigth: 50px;
  width: 95%;
}

.circle {
  width: 35%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 35%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  /*   padding-top:15px; */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-project">
  <div class="project-pill">

    <div class="content">

      <img class="image" src="https://www.demaesschalckgoethals.be/files/images/01a59d76ec5642699cdbb254669ed025.jpg" />
      <!--          <div class="image"> -->

      <!--           </div> -->
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi consequat ex id justo rhoncus, a laoreet felis tincidunt. Aenean non enim varius, fringilla ante vitae, lacinia sapien. Sed malesuada orci ut sapien fringilla congue. Fusce sem nisi, laoreet
        quis nibh lobortis, mattis consectetur dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris eu gravida velit, a pellentesque nisi.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RoelVoordendag/b1jobzk7/1/)

Comment: Does `bottom:0;` sounds familiar? Have you tried using a negative value instead?

Comment: The code provided has a few syntax errors: (`lenght` should be `length` |  `rigth` should be `right` ) fix those first please

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you are intending to do but give it a try :

The problem is because of the `position:absolute` that does not allow it to come on the top.

Play with `position:fixed` and adjust it using `margin-top`,`margin-left` properties.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper-project">
<div class="project-pill">

    <div class="content">

        <img class="image" src="https://www.demaesschalckgoethals.be/files/
        images/01a59d76ec5642699cdbb2546 
         69ed025.jpg"/>

      <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi 
      consequat ex id justo rhoncus, a laoreet felis tincidunt. Aenean non 
      enim 
     varius, fringilla ante vitae, lacinia sapien. Sed malesuada orci ut 
     sapien 
    fringilla congue. Fusce sem nisi, laoreet quis nibh lobortis, mattis 
     consectetur dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus 
      et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris eu gravida velit, a 
      pellentesque nisi. 
      </div>
    </div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Style sheet here

```
.wrapper-project{

flex-direction: column;

}

.project-pill{
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-radius: 4vw;
 background-color: #DBDDDC;
 width: 25vw;
 height: 35vw;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 }
 .image{
  border-radius: 4vw 4vw 0 0;
  width: 95%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  heigth: 50%;
   margin-left: auto;
  margin-rigth: auto;
   }
   .content{
    position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     font-size: 1.7vw;
     height: 100%;
     text-align: center;
      font-family: poppins;
     }
    .text{
      heigth: 50px;
width: 95%;
}
.circle{
height:10%;
 width:10%;
border-radius:50%;
background-color: red;
position:fixed;
margin-top:210px;
margin-left:50px;
  }
```

All the best.

**Cheers**